# Python - How to convert .mkv videos to .mp4 videos

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have two folders.
Download folder and converted folder.

I want to convert files from .mkv to .mp4

```
import os
import boto3
import ffmpeg
from os import path, makedirs

downloadFolder = 'D:'+os.sep+'abc'+os.sep+'def'+os.sep+'downloaded'
convertedFolder = 'D:'+os.sep+'abc'+os.sep+'def'+os.sep+'converted'

#find the number of files in the Downloaded folder
initial_count = 0
for path in os.listdir(downloadFolder):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(downloadFolder, path)):
        initial_count += 1
print("Files downloaded")
print(initial_count)

# convert all files from .mkv to .mp4
source_folder = downloadFolder
for file_name in os.listdir(source_folder):
    try:
        # construct full file path
        source = source_folder + os.sep + file_name
        print("source"+source)
        destination = convertedFolder +os.sep +file_name
        # copy only files
        if os.path.isfile(source):
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
            outFileName = convertedFolder + os.sep + name + '.mp4'
            # convert .mkv into .mp4
            ffmpeg.input(source).output(outFileName).run()
    except Exception as e:
        # print("Exception "+ key['Key'])
        print("error")
        print(e)
```

The below is the error i get because of ffmpeg

```
error
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried moviepy library. But couldnt solve.
Please let me know a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the "converted" folder already exist?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes it exist

Comment: Is ffmpeg binaries available on the system path (or wherever the `ffmpeg-python` package expects it at)?

Answer (score 0):

simply renaming the file did the trick. Split the name and get the name without extension. Now concatenate .mp4. It worked!! I got to know it from a youtube.